# How can I access the image files in PC using react.js ? I am building an app that can annotate image from gallery

Tags: reactjs

I have done the rectangle ,oval and other shapes that could be drawn over image to annotate it.But I can't find any suitable library that can access files from gallery and load it.

Comment: I use this library to crop images on rectangle or round shapes `https://github.com/ricardo-ch/react-easy-crop`. You can discover if it fulfils your requirement.

Comment: I don't want to crop the image .I want to make overlays of rectangle or oval and then label the image. It will be later on be used for machine learning .